# How can we improve the internal wireframe review?

Tags: tools, mockup, expert-review

Our developer team uses Reviewboard for code, but the UX team doesn't have a good solution for mockup reviews. Currently we are using piles of emails in Outlook. I know Reviewboard should work, but I was wondering what other tools UX designers were using for this that may be more catered to reviews of form and function. Some of the challenges are:

1. How to keep team comments lumped together with similar comments, and assigned to an image/story?
2. How to manage past comments, to be able to access information from older sprints?
3. How to search through team feedback?

Does anyone have any experience successfully managing this?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for [Yammer](https://www.yammer.com/). Disclaimer: I work there :)

Comment: Is your UX team all in one place? If so, it's probably best to meet an hour a week (maybe more, maybe less... What ever your needs are) and talk through the designs. Nothing like real time feedback.

Comment: @Majo0od - I second that! This is a matter of communication within the process, and tools are not the only way to boost it. In fact, I believe that tools are the last thing to implement. In many cases it does not matter if you use Tool A or Tool B, as the process in which they are used does not allow them to be effective. So, meeting periodically, preferably with both the Client and the Team may work best. I have used it many times, only armed with a sheet of paper and a pen.

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of web apps that are meant specifically for UX or design reviews. A few that I've used include

- [Invision](http://www.invisionapp.com/) - Also lets you easily create clickable prototypes from your designs
- [MyBalsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/mybalsamiq) - Hosted, collaborative version of the popular Balsamiq wireframing app
- [Notable](http://www.notableapp.com) - allows you to share and collect feedback on designs and wireframes

If you're looking for a more general collaboration platform, a wiki would work well for this use-case, and can also be used for organizing and reviewing other deliverables such as documentation. Some popular wiki platforms include:

- [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview)
- [PBWorks](http://www.pbworks.com/)
- [Media Wiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I used [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/), from 37 signals a few years ago and loved it.

The project owner can archive each set of deliverables, as well as route for approval/feedback.

When we used it, it was web-based, and hooked in with Outlook flawlessly.

Comment: Basecamp is a little overkill for what we're looking for. We already use Rally for most organization/tasks/sprints etc.

Answer (score 1):

For the past year, my team is trying to incorporate Expression Blend + SketchFlow for these mockup reviews.
While I wouldn't agree that Expression Blend is a 'quick mockup' tool, it has a good solution at least when it comes to getting feedback with its SketchFlow Player.

[image: http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ee215229]

Stakeholders, reviewers alike could mark-up and/or insert comments on the mock-up/prototype and save them into a file whereby it can be sent back to the originator.
The originator then overlays these file(s) on his/her design and make the necessary changes. Since the comment files are associated to the mock-up, we package the entire set (mock-up design files and comments) within an iteration for recording purposes. This set is then kept in a version-based depository (in our case, we use Perforce)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I've found the solution we are going with. Since we use Balsamiq (Works fine on Mac), it makes sense to find a solution that works with Balsamiq. Surprisingly, if you get Balsamiq Mockups for XWiki, or other supported Wiki's, it actually costs less and provides a solution to all of our woes.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend adobe Experience design. you can share it with your team or client and they can easily add comment to it.

http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/experience-design.html?sdid=19SCDRPP&mv=search&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!183347083862!e!!g!!adobe%20xd&ef_id=WOYyzAAAAWcjNhBO:20170412152521:s