# Mockup review process

Tags: feedback, mockup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we improve the internal wireframe review?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17836/how-can-we-improve-the-internal-wireframe-review)

I am trying to understand what the best practices are for

1. sharing mockups with clients online and
2. capturing feedback on the mockup from them

Ideally, I would prefer to have them comment/provider their input on the mockup screens. Better yet, it would be great if I can collaborative participate in the session.

I request your input on the process you use and works for you.

Comment: What tools (if any) are you currently using for creating the mock-ups?

Comment: Also, apparently someone else posted [a very imilar question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17836/how-can-we-improve-the-internal-wireframe-review) today :-)

Comment: Have you tried searching the existing questions? There are many similar ones already available.

Answer (score 3):

**On Sharing**:

There are many tools online for sharing in a collaborative environment.  This ranges from the very obvious and simple, Email or [Skype](http://skype.com/) or even [GoToMeeting](http://www.gotomeeting.com/fec/), to complex shared resources in a heavy collaborative environment, [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/).  Each client is different and you should discuss with them how they would like to proceed with this process.  Some clients find email is best.  Other clients find video or instant messaging better.  You need to examine the technical issues facing you and how you can best fit your work into the environment for collaboration.

Setting up the meeting with the client about the mock-ups should be done in a way where you both understand the exact nature of the meeting.  Small groups can be informal but that informality can lead to lost time when topics become tangential to the discussion.

**On Feedback**:

Capturing feedback can be accomplished in many ways.  I prefer to have face to face communication.  I find that video, for clients who are geographically restricted, is most useful as it allows you to see their face as they look at and use the interface.  Confusion and distress are obvious.

Make sure both you and the client are taking notes and make sure you ask for any and all notes they might jot down.  A simple email should suffice for this communication.  You may consider investing into this, [Microsoft Office Live](http://www.microsoft.com/office/olsb/Splitter-EN-US.html).  The client and you can book meetings together, share emails, and the documents.  This is where Basecamp excels again as well.

Finally, consider the sharing very carefully and ask yourself if it is wise to even share the documents in an ongoing process at the time of meeting.  Although you may understand Agile concepts, stakeholders may not.  They may expect a level of polish on your designs you were not prepared for.  An unfinished user interface can work against you in many regards so be careful what you show.

Comment: +1 a well considered answer especially with respect to considering readiness to share, and not just your expectations from the sharing process but those of the stakeholders. Yes they may be sharing your deliverables, but they will have shared much less of the reasoning and process that led to their production. Providing context to, and the story behind shared resources, is key to reducing misunderstanding and misinterpretation that so frequently happens in a distributed environment. A picture is worth a thousand words - just make sure it's all the *right* words.

Comment: Agreed. I would emphasize that getting feedback isn't a technology issue, its a communication issue. You have to ask the right questions, interpret the answers, ask follow ups. You can't just give the client a picture and ask them to email you back.

Answer (score 2):

I asked something similar earlier today. Here was a good answer from thesash:

There are a variety of web apps that are meant specifically for UX or design reviews. A few that I've used include

[Invision](http://www.invisionapp.com/) - Also lets you easily create clickable prototypes from your designs
[MyBalsamiq](https://www.mybalsamiq.com/) - Hosted, collaborative version of the popular Balsamiq wire framing app
[Notable](http://www.notableapp.com) - allows you to share and collect feedback on designs and wireframes

If you're looking for a more general collaboration platform, a wiki would work well for this use-case, and can also be used for organizing and reviewing other deliverables such as documentation. Some popular wiki platforms include:

[Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview)
[PBWorks](http://www.pbworks.com)
[Media Wiki](http://www.mediawiki.org)

Answer (score 1):

We use [ConceptShare](http://www.conceptshare.com) for mockup and design review.

It meets both of your basic requirements:

1. Share online
2. Receive feedback.

It handles a variety of formats and the entire platform has recently been refreshed.

Well worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Receiving feedback is quite a problem. Axure options are not sufficient and rather complicated. Balsamiq is a flash app which is mac-killer (even though mymockups has a decent option to gether some informations from team and stakeholders) and huge no-no for me and my team.

Through the years my team used Axure and dedicated ftp server. We kept wireframes on FTP and all the comments were gathered via e-mail & Jira (now Wrike). Terrible, messy, process.

We've tried to use Notable but it kills interactivity of the prototype.

Currently we're moving to light-weight solution (http://uxpin.com) which is so called "multiplayer wireframing app" and has live collaboration feature (people can actually chat about certain design inside the app and provide changes in real time).

Disclaimer: I run UXPin.