# Is there a service where I can upload product screen shots and get feedback from users?

Tags: usability-testing, mockup

I'd like to upload some mockups that are not interactive, a jpg for example and be able to ask users questions like

*What do you think this service is for?*

or

*Where would you click to log in?*

And it can record both written answers from users and record where they click (bonus for eye tracking).

Also this service should be able to source users to test on.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/mockup-review-process).

Comment: I'm looking for a service that also finds users to test on, not just facilitate the sharing and note taking.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying (actually I didn't read your post thoroughly). I wrote you an answer now :)

Answer (score 9):

Just a few days ago, I accidentally stumbled upon [**Usaura**](http://www.usaura.com/). You should definitely first go to *Take a public test* and run through at least 5 or 10 different tests to see what kinds of mockups and interactivity there is. I think this will be a good solution for you.

**Edit**: I found an alternative solution, called [**Verify**](http://verifyapp.com/). I haven't tried it, but it seems to be even better than Usaura. At first it seems like you need to share your mockups to your friends via social apps etc, but it turns out you can [**buy test results directly**](http://www.zurb.com/apps/797-you-can-now-buy-test-results-in-verify) and choose how many user responses do you need. You can take some [**example tests**](http://verifyapp.com/examples) and see how the reports look like.

Comment: In the case of Usaura, who are the testers? I can't see a way to take tests myself like I can in Five Second Test. Who are their recruits?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe they simply removed the button "Take a public test" a few hours ago. Also, I can't find the page in Google cache or even in Web archive, so I can't show you a screenshot. Fortunately, I managed to pull a [**link**](http://usaura.com/test/1149f530ceab07cc3307) from my browsing history which shows an example test. Good thing with this is that you can continue taking tests from that one. I also found [**this**](http://light.usaura.com) and there you can still see the button and take the tests the normal way. I have no clue why did they remove the button from the main page.

Answer (score 2):

A resource to consider is the [5 second tests site](http://www.fivesecondtest.com/) which can give you valuable inputs on the main focus points on your site.

[Click Test](http://theclicktest.com/) is also another useful resource as it provides good inputs on where users are clicking via heatmaps and click overlays

However the 5 second tests might not work too well if your site has a lot of content (refer to this question [5-second tests vs. the short-term memory](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19007/5-second-tests-vs-the-short-term-memory))

Other resources

- [Usabilla](http://usabilla.com/) (free for 5 pages)
- [ClickTale](http://www.clicktale.com/)
- [Feng-Gui](http://www.feng-gui.com/faq.htm)  : The thing to note about this is  that it does not do actual human usabilty testing but instead it will create a heatmap showing which aspects of the design will get the most attention simulating human vision using algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bagelhint.com

It is easy to setup and the pricing is hard to beat. I used the click test to verify that the item we wanted to be most important was actually what drew the most attention.

They have click-tests that tell you where a person would click when looking at a screen.

A/B test reveals which design is preferred.

10-second reveal and then collect feedback to see what about the page is retained.

Notes - lets others note specific areas of interest or confusion

They provide the link and you pass that around to get traffic to it.

(I think there is also an option to get others to see it for $2/user)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tested this to be honest, but this sounds like something Amazon's Mechanical Turk can help you with (https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome). I've read good things about asking for users opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try IntuitionHQ.com It's really easy to use and has a free offering that might help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion [Usabilityhub](https://usabilityhub.com/) is the best for issues like this.

- UsabilityHub provides a set of online usability tools to help
  you test the effectiveness of your designs and concepts.
- There are tons of users who are open to test your design, wire, page
- There is a community
- You can "buy" answers and earn free credits through answering questions

Answer (score 0):

My answer relates more directly to your initial question in the title regarding receiving feedback, rather than the question of receiving feedback + clicks.

[Discuss.io](http://discuss.io/) is a useful tool I found a while back for receiving feedback, but it does not track clicks. Users can highlight areas and ask questions regarding specific elements. This is most useful for client feedback, or feedback when working in teams where not all members are in the same location.

I realize this doesn't completely answer your question, but I still found it worth sharing.

Answer (score 0):

[Forrst](http://forrst.com/posts) is a nice community that usually gives great feedback, as most of its users are professionals (and/or really good at designing stuff!). It requires an invite to enter, but you can get one quite easily if you use twitter.

It's great for feedback and also for seeing interesting techniques and 'findings'.